# Server does not support secure connections

Tags: c#, email

I'm getting the error "Server does not support secure connections" with my code below.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(exchangeServer);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(to);
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

// ...

client.Send(mail);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `EnableSsl = false`?

Comment: Yes, if I set EnabledSsl = false, it will return the error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Comment: Setting enable ssl to false, more specifically, will only allow for sending emails within that domain, so if your domain was "mail.mybusiness.com", you can only send emails to "person@mybusiness.com"

Answer (score 3):

Your server does not support SSL on the default port; Most won't.

When you set SSL off, you get the message, *"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated"*

That tells you that you are not authenticated. Further, you said in a comment, *"Because if I set UseDefaultCredentials = true and use my own user address in the "from" address, I am able to send an email successfully."*

This is apparently an issue with how the SMTP server is configured. You will need to get appropriate credentials, or have the SMTP server set to allow mail to be sent from the web server.

Comment: But how come I am able to send an e-mail using default credentials without changing the smtp server setting, like adding a port?

Comment: It will send on the default port if you don't specify one. That is the correct behavior. Your credentials have nothing to do with the port being used; It only seems like that because you changed multiple things at once (SSL setting and login settings)... a big no-no when trying to debug something ;-)

Comment: So does that mean the code above is okay? What specifically do I need to configure in the exchange server side so this issue will go away?

Comment: I can't answer that; what I would suggest might not be appropriate in your environment for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What port are you using?  You may find that you need to specify the port in your `SmtpClient` object.

Comment: Is the port required? Because if I set UseDefaultCredentials = true and use my own user address in the "from" address, I am able to send an email successfully.

Comment: I had a quick Google, and a lot of answers seem to point to specifying a port.

Answer (score -3):

write

```
client.EnableSsl = false;
```

Comment: As stated in above comment:**it will return the error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated**